# Trigonometry problem solving in diagram

Tags: trigonometry

A is a point on the $x$ axis and B is a point on the $y$ axis such that $(5,3)$ lies on the straight line passing through A and B . Given that OP is perpendicular to AB and $\angle BAO = \theta $ , Show that OP = $3 \ cos \theta + 5 \sin \theta $

[image]

My attempt ,

$\sin \theta = \frac{OP}{OA} $

$OP =  OA \sin \theta$

OA = $ 5 + ? $

The '?' is what I marked on the diagram as well. I'm not sure how do I get that .

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\tan \theta = \frac{3}{OA-5} $$

$$OA-5=3\cot \theta$$

$$OA=3\cot \theta+5$$

Thus

$$\sin \theta= \frac{OP}{OA} $$

$$OP=OA\sin \theta =3\cos \theta+5\sin \theta$$

Comment: Isn't $\tan \theta = \frac{OP}{OA} $ ? How did you get there

Comment: $$\tan \theta= \frac{OP}{AP} $$ I’ve applied this at the little right triangle in A

Answer (score 2):

[image]

\begin{align} 
|OA|&=5+3\cot\theta
,\\
|OB|&=|OA|\tan\theta
,\\
|OP|&=|OB|\cos\theta
=(5+3\cot\theta)\tan\theta \cos\theta
=(5+3\cot\theta)\sin\theta
=5\sin\theta+3\cos\theta
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The equation of $AB$

$$\tan(180^\circ-\theta)=\dfrac{y-3}{x-5}$$

$$\iff\dfrac x{\dfrac{3\cos\theta+4\sin\theta}{\sin\theta}}+\dfrac y{\dfrac{3\cos\theta+4\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}=1$$

$OA=\dfrac{3\cos\theta+4\sin\theta}{\sin\theta}$

Answer (score 0):

The normal form of the equation of a straight line is
        $$    x cos α + y sin α - p = 0     $$
where $\alpha$ is the angle from the x-axis to the perpendicular from the origin to the line and p is the length of the perpendicular from origin to the line.

So, here, $\alpha=90-\theta$

So, put in the equation and also the length of the perpendicular to the line from the origin=$OP$ and also $(5,3)$ lies on the line. So,
$$    5 \cos (90-\theta) + 3 \sin (90-\theta) - p = 0     $$ 
$$\implies 5\sin \theta +3 \cos \theta=OP$$